# How can I apply -v after I have already executed a command?

Tags: upgrade, updatedb, progress-information

I'd like to watch the progress of a command that I know will take about six hours. I ran an update script and forgot to use -v (or whatever I should have done to "watch" the progress) so I have no way of knowing how far along the process is.

In case it applies, the command I used was:

```
drush cvupdb
```

To upgrade a CiviCRM installation, but this question doesn't really apply to CiviCRM specifically. The answer can apply universally to any already running process. I would have added this question as a comment to very similar posts but I don't have enough reputation yet so I needed to start a fresh topic. Thanks!

Comment: To be honest, I'm not entirely convinced that the command even worked. It didn't ask me to confirm anything. I ran top in a different terminal window but can't tell what I'm looking at enough to see if there are any processes running. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you can't do this in general.

For your specific problem , to check to see if it's doing something, use `top`. Just run the `top` command and the processes using the most CPU will show up on top. If it's working, `drush` should probably be near the top.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the source code of the program, you can have a look to what the `-v` option does. It often simply sets a variable named verbose, something like:

```
int verbose=0
while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "v")) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
        case 'v':
            verbose= 1;
            break;
```

In such case, and if the program contains debugging information (symbol table), it is possible to attach a debugger to the running process and set the variable appropriately:

```
gdb -p <pid>
n
n
...
set variable verbose=1
c
```

Comment: Ah yes, that's a nice approach; and with most current distributions, you can install the debugging symbols at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the first thing a command or script does is to read the parameters, so short answer, no.  And even if the program did some setup work then read the parameters, you would need to hack the memory of a running process.

So to sort of answer the question whether the process is even running, from the command line, assuming your user ID you used to run the process is `c.hall` then

```
ps -fu c.hall
```

Which will list out all processes running under that user ID.  Now, if the process starts a daemon process, it is more tricky, but this should be enough to get you started.

Comment: I looked at the list of my running processes and they don't look familiar. I logged in as root. How do I know I'm not wasting my time and/or just waiting on nothing?

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in [Mark Stewart's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321166/86440), in general there's no way of changing a command's parameters after starting it.

In some cases though, it is possible to determine a process's progress externally. For example, sending a `dd` process a `USR1` signal causes it to prints its progress and continue:

```
kill -USR1 $(pgrep dd)
```

For processes which read or write files, you can use [`progress`](https://github.com/Xfennec/progress) (on Linux only) to track how much they're read or written, and perhaps get some idea of the remaining time — at least, you'll see whether the process is still doing anything:

```
progress -m -c dd
```

would monitor a `dd` process.